Bathroom fan replacement size
Replacing bathroom fan. The current one is a NuTone 769 and the housing measurements are 9”x9”.
I can’t find ANY replacement models of the same size.
I’m guessing this means I need to buy a larger one and cut the drywall accordingly?
Any tips or suggestions?

Is there a replacement for that model?

The new fan needs to be sized for the amount of airflow needed for the size of the bathroom.  That's the first specification.
Then, often it is easier to cut the ceiling to accommodate the fan box. ( I didn't like cutting the ceilings either, but it turned out to be less time consuming than scouring the internet looking for a new fan of the exact size.)
